# What causes an "Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' - the HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state" error?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Context: My team developed an image-based avatar creation tool using HTML5. While it was tested to work well locally, we've encountered issues in production where our users weren't able to save their avatars due to a JS error.

This is the error encountered by our users on Google Chrome:

```
Uncaught DOMException: 
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' - the HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
```

Whereas, this error does not occur for me on localhost at all.

Some articles I read mentioned that "HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state" can occur if the image object is not reachable. However, I've verified (at least locally) that all the objects are intact.

The line which throws the error is:

```
context.drawImage(imageArray[i], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
/*
* Set preview into a canvas drawing for exporting
*/
function setCanvasDrawing () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('avatarCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = (canvas.width) / 2;
  var centerY = (canvas.height) / 2;
  var radius = (canvas.width-5) / 2; //minus 10 is for offset so the circle wont be cut off at the side
  var imageArray = [];
  var counter = 0;

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //drawing background
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = selectedItems['background'].val;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 6;
  context.strokeStyle = '#000';
  context.stroke();

  for(itemtype in selectedItems){
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
      counter ++;
      if(counter == Object.keys(selectedItems).length - 1) //minus one as it excludes background
      {
        //when all images have loaded then draw into canvas.
        for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
          //to clip the image in the circle
          context.clip();
          context.drawImage(imageArray[i], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    // #DEBUG - This is the line causing the Chrome issue

          if(i == imageArray.length-1){
              //convert to file
              setFileFromDataURL(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            }
          }
        }
    };

    img.src = selectedItems[itemtype].val;
    imageArray.push(img);
  }
}
```

Considering that the behaviour differs on production environment versus my local environment, **are there any possible server-specific settings (eg. CSP) or browser-specific CSP settings that may interfere**?

Otherwise, what are the other potential causes of such an error?

Comment: You are not waiting that all your images have loaded before trying to draw them all (many times). So if the second image takes 0.1s to load, and the first one takes 10s, then in the load event of the second one your code will ask to draw the first one which isn't loaded yet. You need to wait for **all** the images have loaded before executing the drawing once.

Answer (score -1):

For browsers to run this JavaScript the path to the images have to be absolute and not relative.

For example:
const currentFrame = index => (
`/scrolling/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.JPG`
)

The above shows images in a subdirectory called scrolling, which path is relative to where the .js file is at, and may work within the preview window of your coding tool, but will throw the broken image error in a web browser.

The below shows the full absolute path for the images which will fix the issue:
const currentFrame = index => (
`file:///C:/Users/Rabin/Documents/Web Site/scrolling/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.JPG`
)